# Authentication in microservice with feign?

Tags: java, oauth, spring-cloud, feign

I have a microservice project, I started using FeignClien in it. But there was a problem, if I authorized one service and from this service I go to another, then on the other one I also need to log in. The code for such an application can be found [here](https://github.com/Pryanic/OAuth). How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem have the following resolving. I've just add

```
   `<dependency>
        <groupId>io.jmnarloch</groupId>
        <artifactId>feign-oauth2-spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>`
```

And also add the following property in application.yml

```
 feign:
  oauth2:
    enabled: true
```